# exclude the files for max last modified date

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

files needs to be move from four folders...how to use logic for exclude the files for max last modified date in this

```
robocopy D:\ven\one1\  D:\ven\one\two1\ /MOVE /xd D:\ven\one\ven_program_kl
```

for an example

```
file1 last modified date:6/19/18 20:00
file2 last modified date:6/8/18 20:00
```

in this case file1 to be exclued and 
file2 to be move to `D:\ven\one\two1 folder`....need simple code
thanks

Comment: Also tried sorting technic but when they are multiple files in a day then max ascending or descnding will not work

Comment: Shree S / [Rupesh Shelar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9786076/rupesh-shelar), your code makes absolutely no sense! None of the directories you're excluding exist anywhere in the source directories so will never be copied regardless. Furthermore you've been told enough times that the usage information of a command is available by entering the command followed by a question mark at the Command Prompt. Please [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51000643/edit) before it is closed and **do not use the comment section to provide any more explanation, code or information**.

Comment: done.....................................

Comment: No it isn't ...

Comment: done......................................

Comment: No it isn't ... **Read and understand the second and third sentences of my first comment before you attempt to comment or edit again!**

Comment: done yes please for chat

Comment: No it isn't ... and no to a chat! Read the usage information `RoboCopy /?`, learn its options, adjust your code to attempt the intended task, explain that task and perhaps you'll get a more positive response.

Comment: Use [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) together with its option to sort by modification date: use [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to capture the result and use the `skip` option to exlude the oldest file; do the copying by [`copy`](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) inside the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy enough in PowerShell. Save the following code in a file such as `keeplast.ps1`.

It is not clear why you are using the /XD parameter.

Sorting by LastWriteTime descending, then skipping the first entry, will produce the other file names. When you are satisfied that the correct moves will be done, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

```
$sourcedir = 'C:\src\t'
$destdir = $Env:TEMP

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcedir |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Move-Item -Destination $destdir -WhatIf
```

If you must run it from a cmd shell, use:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\keeplast.ps1
```

If needed, a .bat file script could be created.

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -NoProfile -File .\keeplast.ps1
EXIT /B
```

Comment: it is incorrect if there are more than one file for same modification date and time then it would not fetch correct files...and however expecting windows script..in cmd form to schedule it

Comment: ok how can i run it from cmd or can schedule in windows schedular

Comment: @ShreeS - Please see the edited answer. Can you schedule the .bat file to run? Of course, you will need to specify the full path to the .ps1 script in the .bat file. Be sure to change `$sourcedir` to your directory in the .ps1 script.